# How to reference grouped elements in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I want to group the following XML file:

```
<record>
    <word>Hallo</word><translit>XUPPY</translit><gloss>gloss1</gloss>
    <word>Bye</word><translit>EHS</translit><gloss>gloss2</gloss>
    <word>Yes</word><translit>KGR</translit><gloss>gloss3</gloss>
</record>
```

Desired output is

```
<s>
    <set><word>Hallo</word><gloss>gloss1</gloss></set>
    <set><word>Bye</word><gloss>gloss2</gloss></set>
    <set><word>Yes</word><gloss>gloss3</gloss></set>
</s>
```

So I use `for-each-group`, as in

```
<xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:element name="s">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="word">
            <xsl:element name = "set">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/word"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/gloss"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

However, I get this output, i.e., empty groups:

```
<s><set/><set/><set/></s>
```

So I am doing something wrong while referencing the elements in the groups. But what? I am sure it must be something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`word` and `gloss` are **members** of the current group, not **children** of it.

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="/record">
    <s>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="word">
            <set>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[self::word or self::gloss]"/>
            </set>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </s>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `current-group()` gives you all the elements in the group, if you want to select a certain element use `current-group()[self::gloss]`.

I would replace

```
        <xsl:element name = "set">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/word"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/gloss"/>
        </xsl:element>
```

with

```
<set>
  <xsl:copy-of select="., current-group()[self::gloss]"/>
</set>
```